# Prove that $1+ \frac{5}{4}x ≤(1+x)^{\frac{5}{4}}≤1+ \frac{5}{4} x+\frac{5}{16} x^2$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How to prove this inequality:
$$1+ \frac54x \le (1+x)^{5/4} \le 1+ \frac54 x+\frac5{16} x^2$$

I tried applying binomial theorem to get this inequality, but I am not able to get it precisely. Please help.

Comment: If you know and are allowed using Taylor theorem, I would try looking in this direction... (And I guess $x \ge -1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Bernoulli's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) inequality, we have
$$(1+x)^{5/4} \geqslant 1 + \frac{5}{4} \cdot x,$$
and
$$(1+x)^{5/4} = (1+x)(1+x)^{1/4} \leqslant (1+x)\left(1+\frac{1}{4} \cdot x\right) $$
$$\leqslant (1+x)\left(1+\frac{1}{4} \cdot x\right) + \frac{1}{16}\cdot x^2 = 1+ \frac54 x+\frac5{16} x^2.$$
The proof is completed.

Comment: The cited Wikipedia article doesn't provide a proof of the inequality.

Comment: (+1) Great. Only you proved it's true for $x>-1$.

Comment: @JohnBentin It does provide a proof for integer exponents and mentioned that generalization to real exponents can be easily done by comparing derivatives. It's a well-known inequality.

Comment: A proof of Bernoulli's inequality is given [here](https://www.planetmath.org/ProofOfBernoullisInequality).

Answer (score 2):

Note
$$ (1+x)^{5/4}-(1+ \frac54x)=\frac54  \int_0^x (\sqrt[4]{1+t}-1)dt \ge 0
$$

and
\begin{align}
(1+ \frac54 x+\frac5{16} x^2 )- (1+x)^{5/4}
&\ge (1+x)[(1+ \frac14x )- (1+x)^{1/4}] \\
& =\frac14(1+x) \int_0^x (1- \frac1{(1+t)^{3/4} })dt \ge 0
\end{align}

Thus

$$1+ \frac54x \le (1+x)^{5/4} \le 1+ \frac54 x+\frac5{16} x^2$$

Comment: It doesn't work for $x<0$. So far only nguyenhuyen_ag's solution is correct and complete (it works for $x>-1$.)

Comment: @NeatMath - I modified the proof, valid for the domain $(-1,0)$ as well. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 1):

Binomial expansion of $$(1+x)^{5/4} = 1+\frac54 \frac{x}{1!} + \frac54 \frac14 \frac{x^2}{2!}$$

Now since $x^2$ is nonnegative we have your claim.

Comment: where are the rest of the terms of expansion?

Comment: Binomial expansion is only valid for integers. This formula is false for $x = 1$ for example.

Comment: The binomial expansion can be expanded to negative and [fractional](https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-binomial-theorem/) powers. The series has been terminated short: they will be equal when the series is continued to an infinite number of terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can make as strong inequalities as you which since, using the binomial expansion
$$(1+x)^{\frac{5}{4}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{5}{4}}{n}x^n$$ and this is an alternating series after $x^2$
$$(1+x)^{\frac{5}{4}}=1+\frac{5 x}{4}+\frac{5 x^2}{32}-\frac{5 x^3}{128}+\frac{35 x^4}{2048}-\frac{77
   x^5}{8192}+\frac{385 x^6}{65536}+O\left(x^7\right)$$

Comment: This holds only for $|x|\leqslant1$. But even restricted to that range, it doesn't go far in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I found that my solution doesn't work if $x<0$. So far only nguyenhuyen_ag has a correct and complete (and beautiful) proof. Others are either plain wrong, or only correct when $x\ge0$.

I found another proof for the RHS.

Denote $g(x) = \frac{(1+x)^{5/4}-1-5x/4}{x^2}, x>-1$. It's not difficult to prove $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ are both continuous at $0$. Since $g'(x)$ is ugly we instead look at $$h(z)=g(z-1)=\frac{z^{5/4}-1-5(z-1)/4}{(z-1)^2}, z>0$$
Then
$$h'(z)=-\frac{3\sqrt z+ 4 \sqrt[4]z + 3}{4(z^{3/4}+\sqrt z + \sqrt[4] z+1)^3} < 0, \forall z>0$$

Therefore $g(x) \le g(-1) = \frac 14 \implies (1+x)^{5/4} \le 1 + \frac{5}{4} x + \frac{1}{4} x^2$. This the same (and better than OP's) result as shown in nguyenhuyen_ag's proof.

---

**My original proof:**

Many inequalities of this type can be easily solved via [Taylor's theorem with the mean-value forms of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder).

$f(x)=(1+x)^{\frac 54}, f''(x)=\frac{5}{16(1+x)^{3/4}} > 0, f^{(3)}(x) = -\frac{15}{64(1+x)^{7/4}} < 0.$

Therefore
$$
f(x) = 1 +\frac{5}{4}x + \frac{f''(\xi_1)}{2!}x^2 \ge 1+\frac{5}{4} x
$$

$$
f(x) - \left( 1 +\frac{5}{4}x + \frac{5}{16}x^2 \right) = 1 + \frac{5}{4}x + \frac{5}{32}x^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(\xi_2)}{3!}x^3 - 1 - \frac{5}{4}x-\frac{5}{16} x^2
\\
=-\frac{15}{6\cdot 64(1+\xi_2)^{7/4}}x^3-\frac{5}{32}x^2 = -\frac{5x^2}{32} \left( 1+ \frac{x}{4(1+\xi_2)^{7/4}}\right) \le 0
$$
where $\xi_1, \xi_2$ are between $x$ and $0$.

Another recent example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3943055/how-to-prove-4-cosx-x-sinx-geq-4-x2-for-all-real-x-with-equalit/3943232#3943232).

Comment: The expansion holds when $\zeta$ is between $x$ and $0$ so if $x>1$ it's also true.

Answer (score 1):

You may like this. Suppose $x\ge0$. Note
$$ 1\le(1+t)^\frac14 \le 1+\frac1{2}t$$
which is derived from
$$ 1\le 1+t\le(1+\frac12t)^4. $$
So
$$ x\le\int_0^x(1+t)^\frac14dt \le \int_0^x(1+\frac12t)dt=x+\frac14x^2. $$
Since
$$(1+x)^{5/4}=1+\frac{5}{4}\int_0^x(1+t)^{\frac14}dt $$
you hav
$$ 1+\frac54x\le(1+x)^\frac54 \le 1+\frac54x+\frac5{16}x^2.$$